# Ionic 1 / cordova how to get device language

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Need help to get the Device language from my Ionic1 Application to set its idiom and translate the content on it.

I only find ways for Ionic 2, have tried with cordova plugis like cordova-globalization http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/ or https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization but throw error with provider or doesn't found functions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the browser language:
Check:

```
navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage
```

Comment: pls check this to the right answer for the next guy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using language for "globalization" then -

First install plugin -> `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization`

then use -

```
navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(function(language) {
   // This will display your device language
   console.log('language --',language);
 }, null);
```

For normal, you can use following to get device language

```
navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage
```